# in my viewcontroller, I add a subview which has a xib, I set the autolayout in the xib, but when i add the view to the view controller it doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, xib

first I have my custom view named FindFriendHeadPublish.h,which contains a xib file as follows,I have set the autolayout,and the view is OC
[image]

and my view controller which named PreviewViewController.swift also has a xib
and I  add the FindFriendHeadPublish view to the view controller, but the autolayout in the FindFriendHeadPublish doesn't work

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = "我的卡片预览"
    var addpreviewView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("FindFriendHeadPublish", owner: nil, options: nil)
    var previewView = addpreviewView.last as! FindFriendHeadPublish
    previewView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false);
    GetUserInfoInterface.getUserInfoWithFUid(UserInfoSaveUtil.getUserInfo().userid, withBlock: { (userInfo:GetUserInfoVo!  , error:NSError! ) -> Void in

})

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 640)
self.scrollView.addSubview(previewView)

}
```

I have check some other problems , but I haven't find a solution, any one can help, thank you

further more, the custom view works well in another viewcontroller which write in OC

and the code above works as follows
[image]

Comment: Please share your code.

Answer (score 1):

First of all add Hieght Constraint to previewView in the nib
then add the following code after `previewView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false);`

```
var constraints: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
constraints.addObject(NSLayoutConstraint(item: previewView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.scrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
constraints.addObject(NSLayoutConstraint(item: previewView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.scrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
constraints.addObject(NSLayoutConstraint(item: previewView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Right, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.scrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
self.scrollView.addConstraints(constraints as [AnyObject])
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Just a correction write the above snippet after `self.scrollView.addSubview(previewView)`

Answer (score 0):

You did not set the constraints for previewView and its superview, which you cant do in IB if the views are not in one file.

```
previewView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false);
let viewBindingsDict = ["previewView":previewView, "view":self.view]
self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[previewView(==view)]", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewBindingsDict))
self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[previewView]", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewBindingsDict))
```

this example sets the previewView top left with the width of the controllers view.
a nice tutorial: http://www.thinkandbuild.it/learn-to-love-auto-layout-programmatically/

it is recommended to use only one view in a scrollview and use it as container for the others.
if you load a nib and set the owner to self

Comment: I tried the code you provided, but it crash with "NSScanner : nil string argument"